# Сортировка столбцов pandas

Tags: python, pandas, сортировка, nan

Всем привет! Изучаю pandas и никак не могу решить одну проблему

Есть DataFrame, который содержит 2 колонки, в котором нужная мне информация разделена между собой пустыми ячейками

Вот пример:

```
    A   B
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   H   1.0
3   G   2.0
4   F   3.0
5   E   4.0
6   D   5.0
7   C   6.0
8   B   7.0
9   NaN NaN
10  NaN NaN
11  NaN NaN
12  O   1.0
13  N   2.0
14  M   3.0
15  L   4.0
16  K   5.0
17  J   6.0
18  I   7.0
19  NaN NaN
20  NaN NaN
21  NaN NaN
22  O   1.0
23  NaN NaN
24  NaN NaN
25  NaN NaN
26  Q   1.0
27  P   2.0
28  NaN NaN
29  NaN NaN
30  V   1.0
31  U   2.0
32  T   3.0
33  NaN NaN
```

Я ищу способ, с помощью которого я смогу определить те строки, которые находятся после и до пустых ячеек и отдельно отсортировать их в алфавитном порядке

Вот что я пытаюсь сделать на основе первого примера:

```
    A   B
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   B   7.0
3   C   6.0
4   D   5.0
5   E   4.0
6   F   3.0
7   G   2.0
8   H   1.0
9   NaN NaN
10  NaN NaN
11  NaN NaN
12  I   7.0
13  J   6.0
14  K   5.0
15  L   4.0
16  M   3.0
17  N   2.0
18  O   1.0
19  NaN NaN
20  NaN NaN
21  NaN NaN
22  O   1.0
23  NaN NaN
24  NaN NaN
25  NaN NaN
26  P   2.0
27  Q   1.0
28  NaN NaN
29  NaN NaN
30  T   3.0
31  U   2.0
32  V   1.0
33  NaN NaN
```

И после этого я смогу удалить пустые ячейки с помощью df.dropna() и получить желаемый результат

До и после частей почти всегда разное количество пустых ячеек, сами эти части тоже содержать рандомное кол-во строк. Я пытался как-то это решить, но ничего не придумал)

Надеюсь я правильно и доступно объяснил и заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать новую колонку, поместить туда что-то вроде:

```py
df['group'] = -df['A'].isna().cumsum()
```

После этого сортировать по нужным колонкам, включив эту колонку с группой на первое место, чтобы по нужным колонкам сортировка шла уже внутри группы между `NA`, а не глобально:

```py
df = df.sort_values(['group', 'B'], ascending=False)
```